# how to redirect myolddomain.in/about-us.html to mynewdomain.com/about-us.html in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, new-operator

i changed my domain from .in to .com but old .in urls still show up on search and when visited it shows "destination unknown". So i want all my old .in urls to redirect to respective new .com urls. how to do that?

as of now only home page is getting redirected from go daddy domain forwarding.

for exampple
how to redirect
myolddomain.in/about-us.html to mynewdomain.com/about-us.html 
myolddomain.in/services.html to mynewdomain.com/services.html

i did not try anything its a empty htaccess file

Comment: "i did not try anything". On this website you are expected to try first by yourself and show what you did, the errors you get and the results you want.

Comment: i don't even know to try